# Parse.com fetch collection limit up to 1000

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, limit, fetch

I'm trying to get all element of a parse Collection with Javascript.

`collection.query.limit(1000);`

doesn't work for me. query propiety doesn't exist in collection.

Thanks!

Comment: It is worth asking why you need to get all the objects at once, as this often highlights an issue that could be solved another way (paging for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the docs here, it should be the other way around: https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#collections

```
var query = new Parse.Query("myClass");
query.limit(1000);
var collection = query.collection();
```